# Expand Model layer

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a pretained model with summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg19 (Model)                (None, 4, 4, 512)         20024384  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 8192)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              8389632   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              1049600   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 5125      
=================================================================
```

I need the version with vgg19 expanded not in a single layer. Something like 
this :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 128)       73856     
.
.
.
** end of vgg16 **
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 8192)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              8389632   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              1049600   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 5125      
=================================================================
```

I have trying to copy layer by layer but I have encountered lots of problems. There exist a way to accomplish this, that also copy the weights?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implemented, you can see the code how I implemented. I hope it will help.

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import *

model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(128,128,3))
flatten_1 = Flatten()(model.output)
dense_1 = Dense(1024)(flatten_1)
dropout_1 = Dropout(0.2)(dense_1)
dense_2 = Dense(1024)(dropout_1)
dense_3 = Dense(5)(dense_2)

model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=dense_3)

print(model.summary())
```

Result.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 32, 32, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv4 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 16, 16, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv4 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 8, 8, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv4 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 4, 4, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 8192)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              8389632   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              1049600   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 5125      
=================================================================
Total params: 29,468,741
Trainable params: 29,468,741
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```